# Почему кука установилась после начала вывода?

Tags: http, php, cookie

Это противоречит моим текущим знаниям о php и http... Как так?

Код:

```
$file='';$line='';
echo headers_sent($file,$line);
echo " file = $file ; line = $line";

setcookie('sdfsdf',234);
```

Выводит:

```
file = ; line = 0
```

И самое интересное: **кука устанавливается**!

Для тех кто не понял: кука установилась уже ПОСЛЕ того, как начался вывод. Это приблуда нового php такая, или wtf?

upd: PHP Version 5.3.3

Comment: суть проблемы в другом ;)

Comment: Ага дошло позже )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Действительно странное, на первый взгляд, поведение. но!
Внутрях пхп происходит буферизация, поэтому куки ставились быстрее, чем наполнился буффер. Есть предположение, что за это отвечает настройка в php.ini:

```
output_buffering = 4096
```

Потому что если добавить до вывода кукисов вот такой кусок:

```
$file='';$line='';
echo headers_sent($file,$line);
echo " file = $file ; line = $line";
for ($i = 1; $i < 500; ++$i) echo 'Hello world!';

echo "<br/>";
setcookie('sdfsdf',234);

var_dump($_COOKIE);
```

то будет ожидаемое `Headers already set...` потому что данных выведется больше, чем 4096, заданное в настройках поумолчанию.

ззыж опытным путем выяснил, что именно так и есть ;)

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 4000; ++$i) echo 'H';
```

тут куки установятся, поставить лимит счетчика больше на несколько единиц (нужно поссчитать насколько с учетом остальных выводов) ти буфер наполнится и вывод осуществится  до куков.

Comment: Да, действительно, проверил.

Comment: Хм... Забавное наблюдение... Вот уж точно "четное число ошибок дает верный результат"...)